# printing a tuple with a tab between the values

Tags: python, file, text, formatting

I have a text file like the one below:

```
this000is00a00test001251!!
this000is00a00test001251!!
this000is00a00test001251!!
this000is00a00test001251!!
```

I have the following code to parse through it:

```
def file_open():
    my_file = open(r'C:\Users\test\Desktop\parse_me.txt','r', encoding='cp1252')
    return my_file

def parse(current_line):
    seq_1 = (current_line[0:4])
    seq_2 = (current_line[7:9])
    seq_3 = (current_line[11:12])
    seq_4 = (current_line[14:18])
    seq_5 = (current_line[20:24])
    return(seq_1, seq_2, seq_3, seq_4, seq_5)

def export_file(current_file):
    for line in current_file:
        x = parse(line)
        print (x)

export_file(file_open())
```

Here is the output I get in the interpreter:

```
('this', 'is', 'a', 'test', '1251')
('this', 'is', 'a', 'test', '1251')
('this', 'is', 'a', 'test', '1251')
('this', 'is', 'a', 'test', '1251')
```

What I want to see is the text formatted like this:

```
this    is    a    test    1251
```

or

```
this,is,a,test,1251
```

Any ideas? Or do you have any good links that explain text formatting in 3.0?

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want to join a list of strings, you can use `join()` like so:

```
list_of_strings = ['one', 'two', 'three']
print "\t".join(list_of_strings) #\t is the tab character
```

Output:

```
one    two    three
```

For commas, just replace `"\t".join` with `",".join`. Join will also work with tuples as used in your example code (It works with any iterable).

Comment: Also see [Format String Syntax](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#formatstrings) in the Python Docs if you want to format values in other ways.